# ¿Como dejar el valor seleccionado usando html.dropdowlist en MVC C# con motor aspx, similar a razor

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

Tengo el la siguiente definición de lista de opciones:

```
 <% dynamic listItems_Afirmacion = new List<ListItem> {
                    new ListItem {
                        Text = "Si",
                        Value = "S"},
                    new ListItem {
                        Text = "No",
                        Value = "N"
                    },
     };
  %>

<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>opcion<th>
    </tr>
</thead>    
<tbody>
    <% foreach (var item in Model)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <%:Html.DropDownList("afirmacion", new SelectList(listItems_Afirmacion, "Value", "Text"),"Seleccione", new {@class = "form-control input-sm"})%>
       </td>
  <tr>
 ......
```

pero quiero dejar el valor seleccionado la **S** o la **N** dependiendo del valor que traiga.El campo para acceder es `item.valor`, que me imagino que en alguna parte debería hacerlo indicar para dejar seleccionado (`selected`).
Me gustaría saber como poder hacerlo?

Answer (score 1):

Podrias usar algo como ser

```
<% (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
       { %>
    <tr>
        <td>
         <%:Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m[i].valor, new SelectList(listItems_Afirmacion, "Value", "Text"),"Seleccione", new {@class = "form-control input-sm"})%>
       </td>
  <tr>
```

veras que cambie por un `for` para tener el index de la coleccion que luego usar en el `Html.DropDownListFor(m=> m[i].valor, ...)`

Si quieres usar el `foreach` tambien se puede pero necesitaras una variable que vayas incrementando en cada iteracion

Answer (score 1):

Considera usar [`SelectList`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist(v=vs.118).aspx) que te ayudaría con uno de sus constructores.

Suponiendo el `model` es un listado (en mi caso una lista de cadena).

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    var items = new[]
    {
        "S", "N"
    };

    return View(items);
}
```

Se consideraría usar:

```
@{
    foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        @Html.DropDownList("Afirmación", new SelectList(listItems_Afirmacion, "Value", "Text", item), "Seleccione", new { @class = "form-control input-sm" })
    }
}
```

El momento de renderizar genera:

```
<select class="form-control input-sm" id="Afirmaci_n" name="Afirmación">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="S">Si</option>
    <option value="N">No</option>
</select>

<select class="form-control input-sm" id="Afirmaci_n" name="Afirmación">
    <option value="">Seleccione</option>
    <option value="S">Si</option>
    <option selected="selected" value="N">No</option>
</select>
```

Comment: ¿+1? Acaso no vió mi error en la renderización. Espero que el OP identifique ese error.